# How do i make a <nav> toggle from underneath a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like a nav (inside header) to be attached to the bottom of a div .menu_bar so that when the nav is toggled it will slide down from directly underneath. The nav is not inside the div and the div isn't inside the nav, they are separate in the html. Currently I can't get the nav to slide down from the div and when I do it only works for that screen size and breaks again when I change width of the screen.

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="submenu" >
                <a href="#">Nielsen Products<span class="icon-arrow-down2"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li><a href="#">Exterior Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Interior Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Odour Control & Air Fresheners<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Exterior Finishes<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dressings<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Glass Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Workshop Maintenance<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Janitorial<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TDS & SDS INFO<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nielsen Catalogue</a></li>
            <li class="submenu1">
                <a href="#">Equipment/Tools/Consumables<span class="icon-arrow-down2"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="children1">
                    <li><a href="#">Valeting, Brushes and Equipment<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tools & Equipment<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Workshop Consumables<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">AdBlue<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>

<div class="menu_bar">
<a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span>Menu</a>
</div>
```

By the way the div at the bottom isn't inside anything apart from the body tags ( I don't know if it shows that clearer enough)

```
    .bt-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.menu_bar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    position: relative;
    background: #FF0000;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu_bar .bt-menu {
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu_bar span {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
}
header nav {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: Where's your JavaScript?

Comment: This should be all of the relevant code but ignore the result because that not how it looks http://jsfiddle.net/1hpo3w46/

Comment: The code and markup for your question goes **in** your question, not just linked.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make the javascript look good in my question so I linked it instead

Comment: Really? When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help.

Comment: Yes because when I used ctrl and K it didn't work, isn't the link enough

Comment: No, links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Again: There's an **entire toolbar of formatting tools**. One of them is the `{}` button. (And again, there's that handy **[?]**.)

Answer (score 1):

Just do some changes , according to fiddle

```
header nav {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Check this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/1hpo3w46/3/

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I wrapped the header in a div and then changed the css for it still doesn't work.

Comment: It is as if it isn't my new css, I set the height to 100% and it clearly isn't 100%...so confused

Comment: Which jquery do I add?

Comment: add jquery 1.11.0 or higher

Comment: I think I have it...<script src="http://cpde.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i have them in my head

Comment: whether my fiddle output is correct ?

Comment: i think there is an issue in jquery-latest.js, better u change that jquery once.

Comment: what shall I change it to, your fiddle result is mostly correct, I just want to have the nav show ontop of everything else, so it doesn't have relative position

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1hpo3w46/4/

Comment: I have it working how I want apart from it slides down and pushes everything on the page down because I gave it a relative position. I don't want it to push everything else down I want it to slide down, on top of everything else. is this possible?

Comment: Nevermind I have figured it out thankyou for all your help.

Comment: I made a few adjustments and now it works